# How do I compare times without hours?

Tags: time, google-sheets, string-formatting, google-sheets-formula, number-formatting

I am admittedly bad at formulas so I apologize if this comes off as stupid:

I need to compare two times for my swimmers and can't figure out a clear way to write a formula to compare their time vs. a cut time they are shooting for.

Ex:
Swimmer has a `2:44.01` in her event, and needs a `2:41.96` for a specific meet.

In this instance, her time is in B3 and the cut time is in C3. How do I write a formula that will display the difference in those times in cell C4, right below the cut time?

Everything I have seen requires a `hh:mm:ss.00` formula or similar but how do I write it so that I don't have so many stinkin 0's in each cell? I wish that it would allow a simple `mm:ss.00` without needing hours to register as time.

My other issue is that in C4, where I want the difference to show up, how do I start that equation? Do I start with `SUM` or `ELAPSED` or what? I'm out of my league here so please help!

Comment: So you need 2 things - format the cells so they don't show hours and then calculate difference between event time and cut time?

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
=TEXT(VALUE("00:"&B2)-VALUE("00:"&C2), "m:ss.00")
```

[image: 0]

...and format all fields as **Plain text**